# Why is my iPhone storage full if my iCloud is empty?

Tags: iphone

This has been bothering me for so long, my phone never has storage no matter how much I delete. I have less than 40 photos, and only around 2 very big games. But that’s not the issue.

Yesterday my mother saw this problem, and choose to buy 50 GB for my phone. That option where you go to settings - iCloud- etc and choose the 0.99 per month plan. This increase my iCloud storage from 5GB to 50GB, but my phone is still at 16 GB! My iCloud only has around 3 GB full, so why  isnt the stuff from my actual phone storage increasing or transferring to iCloud? I had a friend buy this same plan, and it increased the phon storage to 64 GB on top of the 50G GB added to iCloud.

Someone please help! This has been killing me for weeks and I’m tired of it!

Comment: 'Storage' is not 'memory' You bought more online storage, but your phone's memory cannot be upgraded.

Comment: You can buy an increase in cloud storage only. You cannot increase the size of the amount of physical storage on the phone.

Comment: Can we lose the schoolyard language, thank you very much. You cannot increase your phone's memory. That's a physical impossibility.

Comment: I would lose the schoolyard language if people were being helpful! There is a way to increase iPhone storage. Are you telling me that some iPhones just have built in 64 GB and others only have 16 GB? What am I supposed to do with the iCloud storage? Is there any way I can transfer all my normal storage stuff to it?

Comment: iCloud storage is useful for backups & photos, so you can offload some to online storage when your phone gets full. Your phone's memory cannot be updated at all, so if it's full of apps & associated data, then buying additional iCloud storage won't really help. 16GB on your phone is pretty small by today's standards - the only fix is to get a new device with more available memory.

Comment: The smallest device you can buy today has 64GB, the largest 1TB. For those, the 50GB [or even more] online storage is probably vital, even just for backups.

Comment: Well that sucks that I have to get a new phone but it’s been time for an upgrade anyway. I currently have an iPhone 6S Plus. Maybe it’s a bit outdated

Comment: I still have a 6S, haven't yet seen the need to update it - but I got the 64. My even older iPad has only 16 & that's a struggle. You just have to learn to keep them lean, no unnecessary apps or data.

Comment: I can’t really keep it lean. I am keeping it as lean as possible but it’s still too much. I screen record and make videos so that takes a lot of space. I’m just going to have to get a new phone. It’s a good thing that I have a plan where I can get a new phone if i take this one back. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Most space is occupied by photos library, use optimised mode and you'll save significant space in the iPhone. nothing can be done about games etc.

Comment: I don’t have many photos, it’s the apps